# How to not save existed parsed string in file

Tags: perl

I want to parse a single string by using LWP::UserAgent;
what actually I get when I parse strings from Url and saved in file is like

```
https://facebook.com/hello
http://google.com
https://facebook.com/hello
https://facebook.com/hello
http://google.com
```

is there a way to print just a single string in file like :

```
https://facebook.com/hello
http://google.com
```

and its more than 1000 string so its absurd to check it manually

Comment: So, you want to remove duplicate URLs?

Comment: no i want to ignore them from the start

Comment: So you want to remove duplicate URLs from an array?

Comment: yeah thats what i wanna do

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to collapse duplicates, a hash is the tool for the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   print unless $seen{$_}++;
}

__DATA__
https://facebook.com/hello
http://google.com
https://facebook.com/hello
https://facebook.com/hello
http://google.com
```

Iterates the special `DATA` filehandle (e.g. inline) so you'd use whatever file of URLs you've opened. And then test to see if the current line is in the `%seen` hash already - and if it is, skips it.

Doesn't do any sorting though - just prints the first instance.

Comment: It is good style to _always_ include a hashing function in singularization code, even if it simply returns the parameter in the simplest case. It is reusable and easier to find.

Comment: I don't think that a hashing function is good style, so the above answer is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

A hash is the best solution for checking for duplicates as you retrieve input. If you already have an array full of strings and want only one of each string, use uniq from [List::Util](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util#uniq):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 1.45 'uniq';
my @urls = qw(https://facebook.com/hello http://google.com https://facebook.com/hello https://facebook.com/hello http://google.com);
print "$_\n" foreach uniq @urls;
```

Result:

```
https://facebook.com/hello
http://google.com
```